# Laravel 5.8 runs scheduler together with any other command

Tags: laravel, command, scheduler, laravel-artisan

I have noticed that anytime i run an artisan command in the terminal the scheduler is fired, see attached.
Laravel 7 doesnt  show such a behaviour.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izls2.png)

Comment: Looks more like the kernel boots and creates all components when executing `artisan`. To check if the `handle` command is executed, also set a `dump` in the handle command and you'll see it shouldn't have executed.

Comment: handle is not executed for sure